# Openfire how to fix? Error creating secured outgoing session to remote server

Tags: unix, java, openssl, xmpp, openfire

I have a OpenBSD server 5.6, in this server install Openfire 3.9.3.

But I am getting the following error:

error.log

```
2015.02.16 08:59:44 org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalOutgoingServerSession - Error creating secured outgoing session to remote server: riseup.net(DNS lookup: xmpp.riseup.net:5269): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
```

it is repeated several times, and I have no more errors or info in the logs, I have self-signed certificates.

in the buddy list contacts this server appear as a 404 server not found.

I hope for your help no where else resort

thanks

Comment: Please show us your OpenFire Configuration for s2s connections.

Comment: Enabled - Remote servers can exchange packets with this server on port 5269, Close connections after they have been idle for 10 minutes, Anyone - Any remote server is allowed to connect to this server. Use the table below to override the default settings